# PHP Code Not Getting The Right Values From The Database

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am trying to get all the categories stored in a table to be displayed. But for some reason my code automatically skips the first entry in the table, and I am not sure why it is happening or how to fix it.

```
$categorySql = "SELECT categoryName FROM category;";   
$categoryResult = mysqli_query($db,$categorySql); 
$categoyRow = mysqli_fetch_array($categoryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

if ($categoryResult->num_rows > 0){
    while($categoryRow = $categoryResult->fetch_assoc()) {   
    $category = $categoryRow['categoryName'];
    echo $category;
    }
}
```

Database

```
+------------+--------------+
| categoryID | categoryName |
+------------+--------------+
|          5 | Community    |  
|          6 | Restaurant   | 
+------------+--------------+
```

I am trying to get it to display:
CommunityRestaurant

But it is currently only displaying:
Restaurant

Comment: Different driver but same issue. Also you should use the OOP approach everywhere... or the procedural, but don't mix.

Answer (score 1):

You are fetching the first row in

```
$categoyRow = mysqli_fetch_array($categoryResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

and then doing nothing with it.  This line isn't needed and should be removed.